# How to detect if constexpr is supported at compile time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, constexpr

I am currently working in a project where we target several platforms and our codebase is built using several different compilers (gcc/clang/vc++).

For our windows platform, we use VS2013 which currently does not support 'constexpr', and I was wondering if there is a way to check if this feature is supported beyond checking if we are in Windows and the version of the compiler is lower than VS2015.

This way I could decide when to extend an existent type with compile-time generated members using template metaprogramming -involving usage of constexpr- only if this is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two suggestions. [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) and this python program called "cxx11tests" (github.com/sloede/cxx11tests). Running it is as simple as:

```
CXX=g++ CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 ./configure.py
make
```

For Boost, the macro you want is `BOOST_NO_CXX11_CONSTEXPR`.

Comment: Awesome, that boost flag is just what i was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stupid suggestion: just try to compile a little code snippet which contains constexpr and check if there is error.

Comment: I added a final paragraph so I explain my use case. Thank you for your suggestion but I cannot apply it unfortunately.